# Agregar evento a un array de elementos html

Tags: javascript, html5, eventos, dom, style

*llamo por medio de document.querySelectorAll('p'), esto me arroja un array. y luego creo un for para recorrer cada elemento del array y a cada elemento de array le agrego un método addEventListener(), por lo tanto la función que ejecuta, permite crear un style background-color a todos los `<p>` ,pero al momento de crear las instrucciones de la función, me dice que es la propiedad style esta `undefined`*

*¿cómo puedo mejorar el código para que pueda agregar estos estilos al invocar el evento?*

```js
    var p = document.querySelectorAll('p');
  
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++){
                p[i].addEventListener('mouseover', function () {
                    // console.log(p[i]);
                    p[i].style.backgroundColor = 'green';
                });
            }
```

```css
p {
     text-align: center;
     font-size: 1.5em;
     font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
        <section>
        <article>
                <p>Contenidos pagina 1</p>
                <p>Contenidos pagina 2</p>
                <p>Contenidos pagina 3</p>
        </article>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var p = document.querySelectorAll('p');
  
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++){
                p[i].addEventListener('mouseover', function () {
                    // console.log(p[i]);
                    this.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
                });
            }
```

```css
p {
     text-align: center;
     font-size: 1.5em;
     font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<section>
        <article>
                <p>Contenidos pagina 1</p>
                <p>Contenidos pagina 2</p>
                <p>Contenidos pagina 3</p>
        </article>
</section>
```

Estás usando una función tradicional, puedes aprovechar y usar `this` en vez de `p[i]`

`p[i]` te causará un error ya que los elementos ya fueron recorridos

Además, no necesitas un `for`, puedes usar un `forEach`

```js
var p = document.querySelectorAll('p');
  
    p.forEach(el => {
                el.addEventListener('mouseover', function () {
                    // console.log(p[i]);
                    this.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
                });
            });
```

```css
p {
     text-align: center;
     font-size: 1.5em;
     font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<section>
        <article>
                <p>Contenidos pagina 1</p>
                <p>Contenidos pagina 2</p>
                <p>Contenidos pagina 3</p>
        </article>
</section>
```